# Could we use uniroot() instead of optimize() for this minimization in R?

Tags: r, function, math, optimization, linear-algebra

In the last line of my R code below, I use `optimize()` to find the `df2` that minimizes the `ncp_diff` function.

However, I was wondering if I could `uniroot()` instead of `optimize()` for this minimization?

```
alpha = c(.025, .975); df1 = 3; peta = .3   # The input

f <- function(alpha, q, df1, df2, ncp){     # Notice `ncp` is the unknown
  alpha - suppressWarnings(pf(q = (peta / df1) / ((1 - peta)/df2), df1, df2, ncp, lower = FALSE))
}

ncp <- function(df2){      # Root finding: finds 2 `ncp` for a given `df2`

 b <- sapply(c(alpha[1], alpha[2]),
       function(x) uniroot(f, c(0, 1e7), alpha = x, q = peta, df1 = df1, df2 = df2)[[1]])

 b / (b + (df2 + 4))
}

ncp_diff <- function(df2, target = 0.15){
 the_ncp <- ncp(df2)
  return(abs(abs(the_ncp[2] - the_ncp[1]) - target))
 }

optimize(ncp_diff, c(0, 1000)) ## HERE can I use `uniroot()` instead of `optimize()`
```

Comment: can you check on `nleqslv::nleqslv` This function is used to solve the roots of non-linear-equations.I believe it will save you a lot of energy and work in determining which to use between uniroot and optimize.

Comment: Just as a comment, You are using absolute value. Thus `ncp_diff` will always return a positive value, hence uniroot cannot work. But if you ignore the abs then you can use uniroot but not optimize/se

Comment: Ohh its just that I took the interval by knowing that the answer you needed was 336. Let me modify the answer to accept the previous interval

Comment: Since almost everything below 100m does not form feasible parameter space for df2 while using uniroot as lower and upper should yield results of the opposite signs. We can brute force, by giving a default figure if bothsides yield the same sign ie if both give positive or both give negative, then we give a value for example c(1,10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alpha = c(.025, .975); df1 = 3; peta = .3   # The input

f <- function(alpha, q, df1, df2, ncp){     # Notice `ncp` is the unknown
    alpha - suppressWarnings(pf(q = (peta / df1) / ((1 - peta)/df2), df1, df2, ncp, lower = FALSE))
}

ncp <- function(df2){      # Root finding: finds 2 `ncp` for a given `df2`

    b <- sapply(c(alpha[1], alpha[2]),
                function(x) uniroot(f, c(0, 1e7), alpha = x, q = peta, df1 = df1, df2 = df2)[[1]])

    b / (b + (df2 + 4))
}

ncp_diff <- function(df2, target = 0.15){
    the_ncp <- ncp(df2)
    return((the_ncp[2] - the_ncp[1]) - target)
}

uniroot(ncp_diff, c(100, 1000)) #
$root
[1] 336.3956

$f.root
[1] 3.74663e-09

$iter
[1] 7

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

Edit:

In order to use the same interval of (0,1000) we can look for a way to go around a scenario where both the lower and upper values produce results on the same side of the number line. Since this is an error in r, we can go through it by `tryCatch`

```
ncp <- function(df2){      # Root finding: finds 2 `ncp` for a given `df2`

  b <- sapply(c(alpha[1], alpha[2]),
              function(x) 
    tryCatch(uniroot(f, c(0, 1e7), alpha = x, q = peta, df1 = df1, df2 = df2)[[1]],
             error =function(e)NA ))
  if(any(is.na(b)))b= c(1,10)

  b / (b + (df2 + 4))
}


uniroot(ncp_diff, c(0, 1000)) #
$root
[1] 336.3956

$f.root
[1] -2.132438e-09

$iter
[1] 8

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

Comment: Many thanks. In `if(any(is.na(b))) b <- c(1, 10)`, is `c(1, 10)` the alternative interval?

Comment: `b` is very important here, it looks like `b = c(1, 10)` is just arbitrary!

Comment: @rnorouzian i took a base you can make it any, its arbitrary